# How to get city from lat/lng with Google Maps V3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

This is [what](http://jsfiddle.net/tLNya/3/) I've done :

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var location = new google.maps.LatLng(45.930976,10.639744);

geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': location  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert(results[1].address_components[0].long_name);
    }
});
```

but I'd like to prefeer not using address_components[i] which parameter, due to the fact it could be different for each request. How is the parameter to get the city? (or location, or country, and so on...).

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm curious to know what the solution is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I'm reading the API right ([Geocoding API doc)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types), but it looks like it might be 'types:locality'

Comment: Did you ever get this issue solved?  I'd be interested to know how if you did.